# How do I add these php tags to the <ul> tag?

Tags: php, echo, output

I am modifying a wordpress function. I have the following code:

```
$output .= $r['link_before'] . '<ul><li class="bbp-forum-info"><a href="' . esc_url( $permalink ) . '" class="bbp-forum-link">' . $title . '</a></li>' . $counts . '<li class="bbp-forum-freshness">' . $subfresh . '</li></ul>' . $r['link_after'];
```

And I need the ul tag to look like this:

```
<ul id="bbp-forum-<?php bbp_forum_id(); ?>" <?php bbp_forum_class(); ?>>
```

However, I don't know how to add those php tags inside of that code. I have tried it in a number of different ways, but haven't been able to get it to work. Any advice?

Comment: to echo function `<?= bbp_forum_id(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

use the `.` to concatenate strings:

```
$c='a'.'b';
echo $c //outputs 'ab'
```

knowing that, just:

```
$output .= $r['link_before'] . '<ul id="bbp-forum-'.bbp_forum_id().'" '.bbp_forum_class().'><li class="bbp-forum-info"><a href="' . esc_url( $permalink ) . '" class="bbp-forum-link">' . $title . '</a></li>' . $counts . '<li class="bbp-forum-freshness">' . $subfresh . '</li></ul>' . $r['link_after'];
```

Comment: I also thought this is the way it's supposed to be, but it's outputting the ul tag like this: <ul id="bbp-forum-" >  and the classes and id are printed OUTSIDE the ul (right before it). I don't get why it does that.

Answer (score -1):

if you are adding it correctly

```
$output .= $r['link_before'] . '<ul id="bbp-forum-<?php bbp_forum_id(); ?>" <?php bbp_forum_class(); ?>><li class="bbp-forum-info"><a href="' . esc_url( $permalink ) . '" class="bbp-forum-link">' . $title . '</a></li>' . $counts . '<li class="bbp-forum-freshness">' . $subfresh . '</li></ul>' . $r['link_after'];
```

This is hard to answer without further knowlege of the system.

ensure bbp_forum_class(); echoes something along the lines of  class="foo"

if that isnt your issue, your style may be overridden by the li class. ensure you dont have conflicting css!